# Oracle SQL - using SYSDATE to display

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is the table:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
---------------------------------------
4567    102     5/5/2011 3:37:41 PM
9876    102     5/5/2011 3:37:43 PM
1234    104     5/5/2011 12:46:16 PM
9999    104     5/5/2011 12:47:09 PM
9999    104     5/5/2011 12:47:15 PM
```

How can I use the `SYSDATE` to fetch only one or more record(s) using rapid display on a report via seconds 'SS' and/or minutes 'MI'? I know about BETWEEN fxn, but dealing with seconds, it's kind of slippery slope to me. Any ideas?

Comment: The format string `FF` means fractions of a second, but I am pretty sure that it is only valid with the `timestamp` datatype.

Comment: what do you mean with "rapid display"

Comment: Nothing really, just fast to be displayed on the report, since seconds count.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite sure what you mean, but if you want to restrict returned records to a few minutes or seconds old, and assuming `COL3` is indexed, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COL3 > SYSDATE - INTERVAL '3' MINUTE
ORDER BY COL3 DESC;
```

[`INTERVAL`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i78291) can be in seconds if you prefer; or both, e.g. `INTERVAL '01:30' MINUTE TO SECOND` would go back 90 seconds, as would `INTERVAL '90' SECOND`. (Also not sure if this needs to be supplied by the user as a parameter).

---

Still unclear what you are trying to achieve and what criteria you want to use for restricting the returned rows. But if you do want the most recent record and any that fall within a specific period of it, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM (
    SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3,
        NUMTODSINTERVAL(
            FIRST_VALUE(COL3) OVER (ORDER BY COL3 DESC) - COL3,'DAY') AS DIFF
    FROM MY_TABLE
)
WHERE DIFF < INTERVAL '01:30' MINUTE TO SECOND
ORDER BY COL3 DESC;
```

This would return the most recent record, plus any with `COL3` within 90 seconds of it. So there will always be at least one record returned. But it isn't filtering `COL3`, it has to evaluate every row to work out the offset, so it'll probably do a full table or index scan. You may be able to filter the innner select anyway, if you only ever want records from today, for example. If not it might not meet your 'rapid' requirement.

A potentially faster, but perhaps uglier, solution might be:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE COL3 > (SELECT MAX(COL3) FROM MY_TABLE) - INTERVAL '01:30' MINUTE TO SECOND
ORDER BY COL3 DESC;
```

Really not sure this is what you want, or how `SYSDATE` fits in.

Comment: It looks OK. However, I need the first two rows displayed solely on col3, while the rest ones are not important. Those two rows have been populated roughly the same time ‘3:37:41 PM’ and ‘3:37:43 PM’. So, is it possible to have those two records to appear on the report?

Comment: Sorry valmont74, I don't understand what you mean. How are you deciding that you want the first two rows? The number of rows; or the most recent row and any within a few minutes of that; or something else?

Comment: @valmont74: I've added a couple more options based on what I think you *might* mean, but I'm really not sure what you're trying to achieve, I'm afraid.

Comment: The first query provided is helpful in my situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate with SYSDATE. Minus 1 is yesterday. Minus 1/24 is one hour ago. Minus 1/(24*60) is one minute ago. And minus 1/(24*60*60) is one second ago.

This query should show you all records with a date in the last 10 seconds:

```
select *
from my_table
where col3 > sysdate - 10/(24*60*60);
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: Interval is a far better method than this

Comment: Is that just for readability or are there other benefits to using INTERVAL?

Comment: PERFECT...You nail did. This is what I was looking for. In other words, once the report is run and the output is appeared ONCE (like 5-10 sec), the next time to run the report, will only show the output without the last records with a date in the last 5-10 seconds. And I hoped you understood my train of thought. Again, thanks a lot for your help.